# iOS - Update CFBundleURLName and CFBundleURLSchemes

Tags: ios, react-native

iOS - how we can update CFBundleURLName and CFBundleURLSchemes info.plist value from AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Do you mean update them at runtime?  You can't.  The info.plist file is part if the bundle which is read only

Comment: how can i update CFBundleURLSchemes value from .env?